# Why isn't RSS reduced when System.gc() for parallel, but for G1 is?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, garbage-collection, g1gc

I'm using Java 17. I have a container with 2GB and run the following Java program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
        public static Map<byte[], byte[]> m = new HashMap<>();

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
                int i = 0;
                while(true){
                        i++;
                        byte b[] = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                        m.put(b, b);
                        if(i % 700 == 0){
                                System.out.println("Reached limit: " + i);
                                m = new HashMap<>();
                                Thread.sleep(500000);
                                System.gc();
                                Thread.sleep(500000);
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Running it with the options

```
java -XX:+UseParallelGC \
     -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=40 \
     -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=40 \
     -XX:-ShrinkHeapInSteps \
     -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 \
     -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10 Main
```

I keep receiving that the RSS reported by `pmap` of the heap is 800MB, it's not getting lower.

```
     Address Perm   Offset Device   Inode    Size    Rss    Pss Referenced Anonymous 
    ccc00000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0  839680 838812 838812     838812    838812
```

But it's pretty clear that `System.gc()` is applied and not ignored:

```
[5.871s][info ][gc             ] GC(4) Pause Full (System.gc()) 702M->1M(792M) 2.820ms
```

So neither `-XX:-ShrinkHeapInSteps -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:+UseParallelGC` nor `System.gc()` makes RSS being reduced.

I need the RSS to be reduced since most of the time Java heap must be small and it's simply inefficient to consume so much RSS for nothing.

Notably, `System.gc()` can reduce the amount of RSS of G1 GC and works as expected.

Is there a way to do that for parallel and why does `System.gc()` required for G1 and simply full GC is not enough?

Comment: Java doesn't necessarily return allocated memory to the OS (this does depend on the garbage collector and its configuration). And if it does, it will usually not do so immediately.

Comment: `I need the RSS to be reduced since most of the time Java heap must be small and it's simply inefficient`  I'd argue the opposite.  Memory is cheap and engineering time is expensive.  Can you really justify that statement?  What exactly is inefficient here?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So even for `G1GC` such behavior of `System.gc()` is not documented I guess...

Comment: @markspace Well, a host machine has 2GB of physicall memory. `java` process have used heap size `1MB`, but consuming RSS `800MB`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Only for G1 it does, Parallel does not

Comment: User code shouldn't normally call `System.gc()`, and all it does is hint to the garbage collector that it might be a good idea to run (which the GC might ignore or not), it does not change anything to the capabilities or workings of the GC. It only sends a hint to run. It seems that G1GC takes the hint (in this case) and performs a full collect, while otherwise it might simply take a while to do so.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the parallel GC is not capable of returning memory to the OS (though I might be wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel GC never uncommits memory reserved for Java Heap, while G1 may uncommit unused memory (i.e. return it back to the OS). Before JDK 12, G1 could return memory only after a full GC or a concurrent cycle. Since JDK 12, it can uncommit more often - see [JEP 346](https://openjdk.org/jeps/346) for details.

See also: [Memory footprint of a Java process](https://youtu.be/c755fFv1Rnk?t=818)